# executing my applications with cloudsim

Tags: cloudsim

I have downloaded the cloudsim and even executed the examples provided in the examples folder of cloudsim. They are working perfectly fine on my system. 
Now, I have a few applications that have been developed in Java. I want to execute my applications in cloudsim. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not how CloudSim works. CloudSim is a simulation tool that abstracts applications in the form of [Cloudlets](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/Cloudlet.java). So instead of running applications on it, you need to create cloudlets that represent your application's behavior, which can be challenging depending on how complex it is.

See how you can create a simple model [here](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample2.java#L107).

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted the question I read more about cloudsim and even surfed through many websites to get an idea about how I can create cloudlets for my applications. But, unfortunately, haven't been able to get the method.